# Radio buttons don't appear

Tags: html, css

I am using a theme and trying to create a form. But, Somehow radio buttons don't appear. If I create a new file and put radio label it works but not with Bootstrap. Any ideas why? Please see the link below. P.S I use Bootstrap.

[Screenshot here](https://www.screencast.com/t/ZuH6kH2E)

[image]

```
<head>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"/> 
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">        
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>     

</head>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML you are using.

Comment: Show us the HTML + CSS

Comment: Missing CSS for styled form elements

Comment: please post your code , that will be more helpful

Comment: and add  Bootstrap to your tags, it'll help you getting the right answers

Comment: Apologies. didn't know how to include tags here. Please see screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/hz8jRsvbA7dF

Comment: Bootstrap's minified js and css included in the template.

Comment: @Jacky, just copy and paste the related fragment of HTML code. Also, copy and paste any **custom** related CSS code or at least link to a theme you're using. As much as we want to foretell from tea leaves, we just can't.

Comment: @WiktorBednarz here we go http://jeyhunguliyev.com/ais/visa.html

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

You can try this  code:

## HTML

```
<form>
    <br>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1<br>
        
    </label><br>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2<br>
        
    </label><br>
    <label class="radio-inline">
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 3<br>
        
    </label><br>
</form><br>
```

Comment: did you added the bootstrap.min.css file

Comment: I fixed it by rewriting default html styles. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Can you c/c here the head /head of your file.

I think you just put the .css / . js / jquery in the wrong order. So your website isn't charging well.

Comment: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#"/> 
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="css/jquery-ui.structure.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">        
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

Comment: Bootstrap css should be the first css :
"Copy-paste the stylesheet <link> into your <head> before all other stylesheets to load our CSS." - bootstrap.com

Comment: look at the link. May be you can figure out http://jeyhunguliyev.com/ais/visa.html

Comment: I fixed it by rewriting default html styles. Thanks a lot

Comment: Nice ! Don't forget to upvote the answer that helped you in order to help people to find the answer they are looking for. Have a good day ! Btw, I like your website.

Comment: thanks a lot. How to upvote the answer? Didn't get what does that mean, to be honest